# Reload the same route path not work

Tags: routes, sapui5

I would like reload the same path using the routing; 
In `onInit` I have the routeMatched function where I have the calls to the server:

```
this.router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._handleRouteMatched, this);
```

this is the call:

```
var idProduct= "p1"
this.router.navTo("product", {
            id_product: idProduct
});
```

the url path is : `.../index.html#/product/p1`

The first time that I call the `navTo` function `_handleRouteMatched` is launched. Right!

But then, **if *in the same path* I want** (by a button) **reload the same product I would like do it by `navTo` function but** in this 2nd case **the function `_handleRouteMatched` is not launched**.

Wath is the right way to solve the my problem? I don't like write the content of the _handleRouteMatched in the logic when I press the button. **I would like pass always across the router**

Comment: Are you using an ODataModel?

Comment: No Nabi, I use JSONModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router in ui5 is smart enough to detect that your navTo() is going to the current route with the current args. It does not make any sense for the router to trigger the routing in such cases, because you are already there. If you want to reload/refresh the same product again, then you should get a reference to the corresponding binding and call refresh() on that binding. In case you are using an ODataModel this should refetch the data from the server automatically. For more information see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Binding.html#refresh

Comment: thankyou Nabi, not using ODataModel the natural way for me is call the server call to refresh the model when I press the button.